# Formik: Manually Set Field Error On Change of Dropdown, depending on condition

Tags: reactjs, formik

By default Formik checks fields as you touch them (`.touched`). You can also initialize errors using `initialErrors={{..}}`.

I have a different situation: **On Change of a dropdown to a certain item**, I need to manually set a field error, if a certain condition is true. I verified in the debugger that the statement below is reached and `setFieldError` is executed. But it doesn't work: when I print `{JSON.stringify(errors)}` to see the current form errors, this field does **not** have an error in the map.

```
<Form.Control as="select"
                custom
                id="approverDropDown"
                name="processAction"
                value={values.processAction}
                onChange={e => {
                    // Call default Formik handleChange()
                    handleChange(e);
                    // If a specific item is selected, start condition check for custom error
                    if (parseInt(e.target.value) === 2) {
                        // Set Inactive Default 2nd Approver error if applicable
                        // This gets here, and the If is executed
                        if (inactiveDefaultSecondApprover) {
                            setFieldError('secondApproverId', 'Selected Approver is no longer eligible. Please choose a different Approver to continue.', true);
                        }
                    }
```

`setFieldValue` usually works from these change handlers, but `setFieldError` did not. I also tried `setErrors({..})` and that didn't work either. Someone wrote that `setFieldError` shouldn't be used inside change handers: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1278#issuecomment-461036355 But how to solve this, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I could do was `setFieldValue('myfield', null);` and then I have validation that checks for the NULL value of that field. I couldn't use `setFieldError` directly.